# Twisted throws "Can only pass-through bytes on Python 2" for no reason

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, twisted

I am using twisted as my webserver. I am delivering normal text sites and binary downloads with this setup.

I am using the exact same setup on 6 machines. Only difference is 3 are running Debian and the other 3 are running Ubuntu.

On two out of my three Ubuntu machines I am getting this error:

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 571, in dataReceived
    why = self.lineReceived(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 1655, in lineReceived
    self.allContentReceived()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 1730, in allContentReceived
    req.requestReceived(command, path, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 826, in requestReceived
    self.process()
--- <exception caught here> ---  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 189, in process
    self.render(resrc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 238, in render
    body = resrc.render(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/resource.py", line 250, in render
    return m(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/static.py", line 631, in render_GET
    producer.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/static.py", line 710, in start
    self.request.registerProducer(self, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 872, in registerProducer
    self.transport.registerProducer(producer, streaming)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/_newtls.py", line 233, in registerProducer
    FileDescriptor.registerProducer(self, producer, streaming)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 112, in registerProducer
    producer.resumeProducing()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/static.py", line 720, in resumeProducing
    self.request.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 217, in write
    http.Request.write(self, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 1001, in write
    value = networkString('%s' % (value,))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/compat.py", line 364, in networkString
    raise TypeError("Can only pass-through bytes on Python 2")
exceptions.TypeError: Can only pass-through bytes on Python 2
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: exceptions.RuntimeError: Producer was not unregistered for /file/10983801
```

The other runs just fine.

Python version - on all three ubuntu servers - is: ii  python2.7                        2.7.6-8                              amd64

I haven't updated python recently nor did I change something within my codebase. I also tried rebooting -> no success.

I would really appreciate some hints on that. 
Googeling only hinted me to this:
[Running Portia (scrapy) on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021206/running-portia-scrapy-on-windows)
But since I am running 2.7.6 and Linux this shouldn't apply to my situation.

EDIT appending the actual code:

```
class PyQueueFile(Resource):

    def __init__(self):
        Resource.__init__(self)
        self.ipcTalker = talker.Talker()

    def getChild(self, convert_id, request):
        """
        :param request: The http Request
        :type request: twisted.web.http.Request
        """
        try:
            db = database.Database()
            video = db.getVideo(convert_id)

            request.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                              "attachment; filename=\"" + os.path.basename(video['title'] + "." + video['format']) + "\"")
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/force-download")

            fileResponse = File(video['path'])
        except TypeError:
            return Page404()

        return fileResponse


def fireup():
    try:

        myconfig = config.Config()

        root = Resource()
        root.putChild("file", PyQueueFile())

        factory = Site(root)
        reactor.listenTCP(myconfig.webPort, factory, 100, myconfig.webIp)
        reactor.run()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        reactor.stopListening()
```

EDIT 2:
I have also tried to install twisted via pip. Same problem. :/

Comment: You have a program that encounters an error.  Ok, that's a start.  Care to share the program?  Or better, http://sscce.org/

Comment: I didn't append any code of mine, because none of my code does appear in the traceback. Anyway, I have appended the code that should be causing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the chapter "unicode filenames" in https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html explaing this:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename(u'/a/b/c')
u'c'
>>> os.path.basename('/a/b/c')
'c'
```

Anyway your fix will fail for non-ascii characters in the filename, it should be URL-encoded (urllib.urlencode)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion! In my special case it can't happen, because I am filtering all non-ascii characters in another part of my app. I will accept your answer, since you gave me the hint :)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the mailing list I could fix the problem.

It was caused by a unicode string.

Changing this line:

```
"attachment; filename=\"" + os.path.basename(video['title'] + "." + video['format']) + "\"")
```

to this:

```
"attachment; filename=\"" + str(os.path.basename(video['title']) + "." + video['format']) + "\"")
```

solves the problem. But I still have no idea why this didn't happen on all platforms?